# Get the HTML of $(this) with JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I'm transversing a table with jquery:

```
$('table#table_semiter tr').each(function(index)
{
   console.log($(this).html());
}
```

I want to return the html inside of $(this), how can I do that?
$(this) should have all the elements of the tr table right?? I mean each one of them.

**EDIT** I solved that now, I was usinf $(this) outside the each() loop.
Sorry.

Comment: Why isn't this working? Any error? Show us how your HTML is structured, maybe your `jQuery selector` is wrong.

Comment: More than likely you are executing this script before the table is loaded into the DOM and as a result, nothing happens because the set of matched elements is empty. Try wrapping it in `$(function(){ /* code */ });` to wait for the DOM to load.

Comment: But I'm getting null con the console.log. It already has the  $(function(){ /* code */ }); it runs inside it. This is my table structure http://pastie.org/10364102#

Answer (score 0):

You're very close!

From the loop you have there, it looks like you're trying to iterate over each `<tr>`, so `$(this)` would be the jQuery object referencing the current row. Calling `$(this).html()` would return the row element and all its children, yes.

If you want the whole table element, all you would need is `$('#table_semiter').html()`, assuming you have only one element with that ID.